# How to match the whole traceback message and not stop early using regex

Tags: python, regex

Here's the python code:

```
st = """
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/builder_task.py", line 279, in do_one_task
    raise RecoverableBuildException("test error")
common.exceptions.BuildException: test error
"""

st2 = """
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/builder_task.py", line 279, in do_one_task
    raise RecoverableBuildException("test error")
common.exceptions.BuildException
"""

EXCEPTION_PATTERN = re.compile(
    r"Traceback \(most recent call last\):(?s).*?([\w\.]*(?:Exception|Error))(: .*?\n)?"
)
ex_match = EXCEPTION_PATTERN.findall(st)
ex_match2 = EXCEPTION_PATTERN.findall(st2)
```

I expect to match the whole stacktrace and capture

`("common.exceptions.BuildException", ": test error")` for st
`("common.exceptions.BuildException", "")` for st2

however it matched from beginning to "raise RecoverableBuildException" and captured

`('RecoverableBuildException', '')` for st and `('', '')` for st2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get the first capturing group because you match `.*?` which is non greedy and then capture in a group matching zero or more times a word character or a dot `[\w\.]*` followed by either Exception or Error. The first time that will match is `RecoverableBuildException` and is captured group 1.

What follows is `(: .*?\n)?` but after matching the first group there is no `:` to match so the second group does not match.

You might use::

`Traceback \(most recent call last\):(?:\n.*)+?\n(.*?(?:Exception|Error):)\s*(.+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5rWj4P/1)

That will match:

- `Traceback \(most recent call last\):` Match literally
- `(?:\n.*)+?` Repeat in a non capturing group matching a newline followed by 0+ times any character
- `\n(.*?(?:Exception|Error):) Match newline and capturinggroup 0+ characters non greedy and than match Exception of Error followed by`:`
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace characters
- `(.+)` Capturing group 1+ times any character

For example:

```
EXCEPTION_PATTERN = re.compile(
    r"Traceback \(most recent call last\):(?:\n.*)+?\n(.*?(?:Exception|Error):)\s*(.+)"
)
ex_match = EXCEPTION_PATTERN.findall(st)
print(ex_match)  # [('common.exceptions.BuildException:', 'test error')]
```

Comment: clear and works, thanks! And I learnt how to match multiple lines without using (?s) mode.

Comment: Follow up: what if there is no ": test error" after the ex name (see my st2 in edited question)? In that case your solution does not match. Thanks. @The fourth bird

Comment: @Lee You might for example match the error message stucture with word characters separeted by dots `Traceback \(most recent call last\):(?:\n.*)+?\n(\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.\w+(?:Exception|Error)\b)(?::\s*(.*))?`  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f2mtRn/1/)

Comment: @Lee You unchecked the mark as answered. Did my last example not work for you?

Comment: Yeah, the init one did not work. Now the one in your comment works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by understanding that any decent user-defined Exception class ends with either "Exception" or "Error" (OK, looks like you already have this down). Now, you can use `re.search`

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'(?<=\n)(.*?(?:Exception|Error)):\s*(.*?)(?=\n|$)', st).groups()
('common.exceptions.BuildException', 'test error')
```

This is a good first step. The regex is as follows:

```
(?<=\n)              # lookbehind for newline
(                    # first capture group
.*?                  # match anything (non-greedy)
(?:Exception|Error)  # class name should end with "Exception" or "Error"
)
:                    # colon (literally)
\s*                  # zero or more spaces
(.*?)                # non-greedy match for the trailing text 
(?=\n|$)             # lookahead for EOL (EOS)
```

You can modify the lookbehind to match the start-of-line if you wanted to. Change `(?<=\n)` to `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\n))`.

Answer (score 1):

The ".*?" in the middle of your regex is non-greedy: it will match as little as possible to satisfy the expression. Because the "(: .*?\n)?" is optional (that's what the final '?' does: match 0 or 1 of the stuff in the parens) the "Exception" at the end of "RecoverableBuildException" satisfies the expression.

There are two ways to get the results you want:

- Remove the '?' from the ".*?" in the middle to make it greedy, so that it matches as much as possible.
- Move the ':' before the final parenthetical so the expression ends with "|Error)):( .*?\n)?" (or even just removing all but the ':', so it ends with "|Error)):").